# How to put an arrow as a selector on Seekbar

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to put an arrow to my `Seekbar` (on bottom side).
I used to use this circle as a thumb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="oval">
 <gradient
  android:startColor="#AAA"
  android:endColor="#FFF"
  android:angle="-90" />
 <size
  android:width="30dp"
  android:height="30dp" />
 <stroke
  android:width="1dp"
  android:color="#FFF" />
</shape>
```

But now I'd like to use an arrow, how do I paint an arror or a triangle?

This is my `Seekbar`

```
<Seekbar
android:id="@+id/custom_seek_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
            android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And is any way to change the color of it?

Answer (score 1):

> how do I paint an arror or a triangle?

You can do it with `rotate`.

This is an example to how to make a trianglo from bottom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="45"
    android:pivotX="-35%"
    android:pivotY="85%">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#0912ce" />
        <size
            android:width="20dp"
            android:height="20dp" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

It would like like this :

[image]

Also, if you play with

```
android:fromDegrees="45"
android:pivotX="-35%"
android:pivotY="85%"
```

A little bit you can move the triangle wherever you want, for instance to top :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="-45"
    android:pivotX="-85%"
    android:pivotY="-10%">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#0912ce" />
        <size
            android:width="20dp"
            android:height="20dp" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

And it would look like this :

[image]

Then you are free to change the `android:thumb` attribute from your `SeekBar` and change it for your new thumb.

> And is any way to change the color of it?

You have to change the `<solid android:color="#0912ce" />` to whatever you want.